# jQuery Datapicker limit from to

Tags: jquery, datapicker

When the `from-date` is picked I want that there is just the possibility of **3-7 days** for the `to-date`.  so the from-to should be `min 3 days` and `max 7 days`. How can i do that?

```
 $(function() {
  $.datepicker.setDefaults({minDate: 0, changeMonth: true, numberOfMonths: 1});
  $('#datepicker').datepicker({onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
        $('#datepicker').datepicker('option', 'minDate', selectedDate);
        setTimeout(function() { $('#datepicker1').focus(); }, 0);
  }});
  $('#datepicker1').datepicker({onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
        $('#datepicker1').datepicker('option', 'maxDate', selectedDate);
  }});
});
```

Comment: Try `$('#datepicker').datepicker('option', 'minDate', selectedDate +3);` and similary for `maxDate`.. can you try creating a fiddle?

Comment: nothing happens here

Comment: Can you create a demo in **jsfiddle**?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xBB5x/10028/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something simple like this:

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
      var newToDateStart=new Date(selectedDate);//convert selectedDate to Date object
      newToDateStart.setDate(newToDateStart.getDate()+3) //todate start
      var newToDateEnd=new Date(selectedDate);
      newToDateEnd.setDate(newToDateEnd.getDate()+7);//todate end
      $('#datepicker1').datepicker('option', 'minDate', newToDateStart);
      $('#datepicker1').datepicker('option', 'maxDate', newToDateEnd);
      //set min and maxdate to datepicker1
      setTimeout(function() { $('#datepicker1').focus(); }, 0);
}});
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/xBB5x/10029/)**

Answer (score 1):

> the from-to should be min 3 days and max 7 days

You need to set the `minDate` and `maxDate` of the other datepicker when a date is selected in the first datepicker. This, as you have rightly figured out needs to be done in the `onSelect` event handler.

However, note that the parameter which is passed to `onSelect` is string. So, it would be better and easier if you just extracted the date using `getDate` and use that to define your range of 3-to-7 days.

Here is an example:

```
$("#fromDate").datepicker({ 
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd", 
    onSelect: function() {

        // define a range object
        var dateRange = {min:null, max:null}, 

        // get the selected date from the first datepicker
            selectedDate = $('#fromDate').datepicker('getDate');

        dateRange.min = selectedDate.getDate() + 3; // add 3 days for min
        dateRange.max = selectedDate.getDate() + 7; // add 7 days for max

        // assign min and max to minDate and maxDate of second datepicker
        $('#toDate').datepicker('option', 'minDate', dateRange.min);
        $('#toDate').datepicker('option', 'maxDate', dateRange.max);

        // set the focus to the second datepicker
        setTimeout(function() { $('#toDate').focus(); }, 0);
    }
});
```

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/ryhkkap3/**

**Snippet:**

```js
$("#fromDate").datepicker({ 
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd", 
    onSelect: function() {
        var dateRange = {min:null, max:null},
         selectedDate = $('#fromDate').datepicker('getDate');
        dateRange.min = selectedDate.getDate() + 3;
        dateRange.max = selectedDate.getDate() + 7;
        $('#toDate').datepicker('option', 'minDate', dateRange.min);
        $('#toDate').datepicker('option', 'maxDate', dateRange.max);
        setTimeout(function() { $('#toDate').focus(); }, 0);
    }
});
$("#toDate").datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd" });
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<input id="fromDate" />
<input id="toDate" />
```

.

Comment: when I use that code, the datepicker doesnt shows up.. fiddle works but when including it into my site it doesnt work

Comment: Must be something else going on. If it works in fiddle and if it works in the snippet, then there is no reason it wouldn't work elsewhere. Check console to see if you are getting any errors. That will give you an idea.

Comment: I can't say for third-party sites. Just ensure you have proper versions of jquery, jquery ui, and css in correct order.